# Translate API response to nullable String

Tags: oop, kotlin, design-patterns, software-design

An API I consume returns (among other fields) a mandatory `telephone1` and an optional `telephone2`. However, the JSON I fetch always contains both fields and a missing entry is displayed as an empty string.

```
{
   "telephone1": "+1 555 1234",
   "telephone2": ""
}
```

When the response is mapped to a pojo, is it preferable to translate the empty string to null? Such that:

```
data class(
   val telephone1: String,
   val telephone2: String?
}
```

To me, this better communicates the possible states. Should I, though? Are there drawbacks?

Comment: Which API do you actually use?

Comment: An internal api at a big corporate I'm working at. This means it's not public, but I do not have influence on it either.

Comment: You asking "How to implement this (de)serialization?" or "What is better to emphasize absence of string value - null or empty string?"

Comment: What the better way is to emphasize absence of string value - null or empty string. And if the choice of the backend developer - he picked an empty string - should have any influence on my choice.

Answer (score 1):

At the first sight, problem boils down to different checks before further data processing: `x == null` or `x.isEmpty()`. But while nullability check is generally enforced by kotlin compiler (unlike unemptiness), it seems to be a better option.

But there are still some situations when usage of `null` (without any compiler errors) may lead to problems in runtime (mainly related to interop with languages without enforced nullability): like implicit convertion of `null` to literal string `"null"` (when concatenating with another string), or even NPE when passed to method accepting `String!` ([platform type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types)) and not annotated properly.

Sticking to DDD principles, the better option would be declaration of separate datatypes:

```kotlin
sealed class OptionalPhoneNumber
data class PhoneNumber(val value: String) : OptionalPhoneNumber() //You may also add some checks in init block that `value` is really a phone number, not just a set of random chars
object EmptyPhoneNumber : OptionalPhoneNumber()
```

and defining your data class as:

```kotlin
data class Data (
    val telephone1: PhoneNumber,
    val telephone2: OptionalPhoneNumber
)
```

Type system will enforce you to do `x is PhoneNumber` checks, and thanks to smart casts it's further usage will be type-safe:

```kotlin
if (telephone2 is PhoneNumber) {
    println(telephone2.value)
}
```

Comment: You say 'mainly related to interop with languages without enforced nullability', what if that interop is not there? It's a mix of Java and Kotlin; new code is written in Kotlin and this pojo will only be used within new features. What non-interop problems could there be?

Comment: And, is this not an example of reinventing null? https://medium.com/@elizarov/dealing-with-absence-of-value-307b80534903

Comment: >is this not an example of reinventing null

No, it's not. `EmptyPhoneNumber` represents absence of `OptionalPhoneNumber`, not general absence of data of some type (as `null` or `None` in `Optional<T>` does).
If you define, for instance, `OptionalAddress` in the same style, there would be `EmptyAddress`, distinguishable from `EmptyPhoneNumber`.

Comment: >What non-interop problems could there be

Aside from mentioned implicit convertion to "null" string, usage of `null` relaxes type system a bit. This will compile without warnings and work in runtime: 
`val a: PhoneNumber? = null; val b: Address? = a as Address?`. This will issue compiler warning (`This cast can never succeed`) and runtime exception: `val a = EmptyPhoneNumber; val b: OptionalAddress = (a as OptionalAddress)`

It may not be an actual problem, rather just refusal of some extra protection.